# B2C changes my custom subdomain to an onmicrosoft.com subdomain; redirect_uri_mismatch; AADB2C90006

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

My webapp uses B2C for authentication.  Everything works fine when I register my application with a default domain (*tenant*.onmicrosoft.com) or a simple custom domain (sampledomain.com).

I want to use a subdomain for authentication (*login*.sampledomain.com) and a separate subdomain for each of my partner orgs (*partner1*.sampledomain.com, *partner2*.sampledomain.com) and I've followed the instructions at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#limitations with no success.

When I perform the authentication challenge 
`var redirectUrl = "https://login.sampledomain.com/auth-callback";
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl })`

The error message shows the *wrong* value for my subdomain:

> "*AADB2C90006: The redirect URI
>   https://login.sampledomain.onmicrosoft.com/ provided in the request is
>   not registered for the client*"

So the subdomain I've configured 'login.**sampledomain.com**' appears to B2C with the incorrect value 'login.**sampledomain.onmicrosoft.com**'.

Is there some other properties or configuration settings I can provide so B2C doesn't manipulate my subdomain.

Has anyone else got custom subdomain working with B2C, is it possible?

Comment: The `AuthenticationProperties.RedirectUri` property refers to the return URL that is redirected to *after* the B2C token have been validated by the authentication middleware. What have you set the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.CallbackPath` property to in the startup class? This is what is sent as the `redirect_uri` parameter in the B2C authentication request.

Comment: How did follow the document to add Reply URL but failed?  Any error messages? You must add `https://sampledomain.com`,`https://partner1.sampledomain.com`, `https://partner2.sampledomain.com` in the Reply URL. Note: you cannot add different domains in Reply URL.

Answer (score 1):

Customer owned domains for **Authentication** / **Tokens** is **not** currently supported! All authentication/authorization requests should go to https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/[authorize|token]. The fact that you will register your own domain with Azure AD will not change that fact.

There is already an idea with enough votes and in planing to support that requirements: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334317-customer-owned-domains

In addition, you can configure multiple reply-urls, with the note - all reply URLs shall belong to the same root domain: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#limitations

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I tried updating the CallbackPath (original value was '/') but it didn't make a difference, the same error occurred. 
I also created a new application registration following the instructions carefully, and likewise the same error occurred.

Given those changes had no effect, it appears B2C is deriving the *wrong* redirect URL from **my AAD tenant name** not from the **redirect URL** settings in the request or in the application registration.

So instead of building the metadata address for the OAuth exchange using my AAD tenant name, I tried the tenant ID (GUID).

That is, instead of using the tenant name in the URL 
  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp`**`/sampledomain.com/`**
      `B2C_1_MySignInPolicy/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

I used the tenant ID in the URL 
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp`**`/1234abcd-1111-abcd-2222-abcd1234abdc/`**
      `B2C_1_MySignInPolicy/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

The redirectUri in the request is `https://login.sampledomain.com/`

And just like that... IT WORKED.  No more redirect_uri_mismatch, AADB2C90006 error.

I still have to test across different custom subdomains and policy types, but I can now sign into the application.

There is still a nasty bit of trial and error here, so if anyone can share information on what is happening I'd love to have a clearer picture.